# Lecture Capture Implementation: Synced Video and Slides Side by Side

Tags: youtube, powerpoint, video-capture, synchronization, screen-capture

I would like to take a YouTube video of a lecture and sync it with another area displaying the (powerpoint/pdf) slides being discussed in the lecture.

For example, [knoodle.com](http://www.knoodle.com) does this but for a price. I wonder if anyone has implemented something like that and what framework (Flash, HTML5, etc) they used.

Another good specific example can be found [here](http://ie.arcticfoxtv.com/146/managing-inventory-out-through-intense-focus-on-forecast-bias-reduction-). It shows exactly the kind of video-slide side-by-side visual I'm looking to create.

Comment: this is more of a superuser.com question - but check out Camtasia from www.techsmith.com

Comment: Parleys.com is in the neighbourhood of what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [authorpoint](http://www.authorgen.com/authorpoint/index.htm) software. It does that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of [presentz.org](http://presentz.org/).

Presentz is an opensource software that lets you mix youtube/vimeo/video files with slideshare/speakerdek/images.

It's also free to use.

Comment: I like the 'mash' approach.

Comment: The presentz website interface is glitchy not able to produce an output! have you tried using the JS files ?

Answer (score 1):

onion.tv provides the functionality you are looking for and many others that can enrich video presentations and overall engagement with videos. It's hosted online - videos stays where they are e.g. at youtube and metadata stays at onion.tv